# Is a*b=|a-b| is binary operation over Z+

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations

$a*b=|a-b|$
a,b belongs to Z+

I'm trying to find that it's a binary operation or not.

So I check associativity
As
Take 1, 2,3

1*(2*3)=1*|2-3|=1*1=|1-1|=0

(1*2)*3=|1-2|*3=1*3=|1-3|=2

Not equal

Also 
If a=b
a*b=|a-a|=0 not in Z+

I conclude that * is not a binary operation

Is my approach right. Or not.

Comment: Just because it isn't associative doesn't mean it isn't a binary operation. It just is a nonassociative binary operation.

Comment: A binary operation is usually just defined as a mapping that takes two elements of some set and produces a third element of said set (without any comment on associativity)

Comment: If $a=b$ one gets zero, not a positive integer... ( if that's what you mean by Z+, else specify).

Comment: OP (question asker) still has not clarified whether Z+ is the *positive* integers, or if not, what set Z+ is meant to be.

Comment: Z+ means positive integer or Natural Numbers {1,2,3,...} @coffeemath

Comment: Then not a binary operation, since $|a-b| not in Z+ when $a=b.$

Answer (score 1):

I am going to turn the comments into a community wiki answer.

A binary operation just takes two numbers of a set and returns a number of the same set.  Associativity is not required.  We accept subtraction on the integers as an operation, but $(a-b)-c \neq a-(b-c)$.  In your case if $a=b, a*b=0$, which is not a member of $\Bbb Z^+$, so it is not an operation.